# Button disable and enable button based on condition

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-data

I am trying to make the button enable when value return true. Even my function returns correct value but but not working as per my expectations.

This is my function:

```
  buttondisable() {​​​​​ 

    this.store.select(transcriptionSelector).pipe( 

      takeUntil(this.transcriptSubject) 

    ).subscribe(data => {​​​​​ 

      if (data.uiState === 'LOADED' || data.uiState === 'SAVED') {​​​​​ 

        if (data.text[0].status === 'Y') {​​​​​ 

           this.submitted = true; 

        }​​​​​ else {​​​​​ 

          this.submitted = false; 

        }​​​​​ 

      }​​​​​ 

      return this.submitted; 

    }​​​​​); 

  }​​​​​
```

HTML:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="accent" [disabled]="submitted? true: null" 
>{​​​​​{​​​​​transcriptButtonText}​​​​​}​​​​​</button>
```

Comment: can you check whether the disabled status is changing in dev tools chrome

Comment: whats the initial values of submitted?

Comment: Are you actually calling the function buttondisable() somewhere?

Comment: Are you asking for html screen or ts file

Comment: In the TS file?

Comment: Yes. I am calling that function in ngonint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wont work, because you are assigning Y to the submitted var.

Try:

```
if (data.text[0].status === 'Y') {​​​​​ 
  // this.submitted = data.text[0].status === 'Y'; 
  console.log( this.submitted); 
  this.submitted = true; 
}​​​​​ else {​​​​​ 
  console.log(this.submitted); 
  this.submitted = false; 
}​​​​​
```

Comment: Then how can check the status and assign the value

Comment: You are already checking the status in the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
private buttondisable() {​​​​​
this.store.select(transcriptionSelector).pipe(
  takeUntil(this.transcriptSubject)
).subscribe(data => {​​​​​
      let flag = false;
      console.log(data);
      if (data.uiState === 'LOADED' || data.uiState === 'SAVED') {​​​​​
        if (data.text[0].status === 'Y') {​​​​​
          this.submitted = true;
          flag = true;
        }​​​​​ 
      }​​​​​
      return flag;
    }​​​​​);
```

Comment: Flag also Boolean value right

Comment: clear private and try again . also type of this function is void and change it to boolean